# Gerrit plugin installation issues

Tags: maven, gerrit

I am trying to install the [Gerrit plugin](https://github.com/davido/gerrit-oauth-provider).

Here's my understanding and steps (please spare me if I go wrong somewhere as I am a novice):

- This repository contains a Buck file, which means I need to install 'buck' (as specified [here](https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/dev-buck.html#_installation)) (Done)
- Running `buck build <folder>` won't work as I need to be in the gerrit tree in order to run it. This is where I got stuck. I cloned the [gerrit source code](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit) and ran `buck build gerrit` in order to build this project, and as specified in the above doc). However, I got the following error:

  ```
  [+] PARSING BUILD FILES...0.2s
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/buck/src/com/facebook/buck/parser/buck.py", line 872, in <module>
  main()
    File "/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/buck/src/com/facebook/buck/parser/buck.py", line 867, in main
  buildFileProcessor.process(build_file.rstrip())
    File "/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/buck/src/com/facebook/buck/parser/buck.py", line 800, in process
  build_env['BUILD_FILE_SYMBOL_TABLE'])
    File "/Users/prashant/Documents/workspace/testPlugin/src/cookbook-plugin/lib/./gerrit/BUCK", line 1, in <module>
  include_defs('//bucklets/maven_jar.bucklet')
    File "/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/buck/src/com/facebook/buck/parser/buck.py", line 78, in invoke
  return self.func(*args, **updated_kwargs)
    File "/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/buck/src/com/facebook/buck/parser/buck.py", line 702, in include_defs
  execfile(include_file, build_env['BUILD_FILE_SYMBOL_TABLE'])
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/prashant/Documents/workspace/testPlugin/src/cookbook-plugin/lib/bucklets/maven_jar.bucklet'
  BUILD FAILED: Parse error for BUCK file ./gerrit/BUCK: End of input at line 1 column 1
  ```

I'm not sure how to install this plugin. I even tried converting it into a maven project, however, it didn't work. Can someone please point out the issue here?

Edit:
I've been able to run `buck build gerrit` successfully by navigating into the newly cloned folder (a level down). Have also ran `buck build api` successfully. But running `buck build plugins/oauth:gerrit-oauth-provider` gives me following error:

```
/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/gerrit/plugins/oauth/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/oauth/GitHubOAuthService.java:18: error: package com.google.gerrit.extensions.auth.oauth does not exist
import com.google.gerrit.extensions.auth.oauth.OAuthServiceProvider;
                                          ^
/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/gerrit/plugins/oauth/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/oauth/GitHubOAuthService.java:19: error: package com.google.gerrit.extensions.auth.oauth does not exist
import com.google.gerrit.extensions.auth.oauth.OAuthToken;
                                          ^
/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/gerrit/plugins/oauth/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/oauth/GitHubOAuthService.java:20: error: package com.google.gerrit.extensions.auth.oauth does not exist
import com.google.gerrit.extensions.auth.oauth.OAuthUserInfo;
                                          ^
/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/gerrit/plugins/oauth/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/oauth/GitHubOAuthService.java:21: error: package com.google.gerrit.extensions.auth.oauth does not exist
import com.google.gerrit.extensions.auth.oauth.OAuthVerifier;
                                          ^
/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/gerrit/plugins/oauth/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/oauth/GitHubOAuthService.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
class GitHubOAuthService implements OAuthServiceProvider {
                                ^
  symbol: class OAuthServiceProvider
/Users/prashant/Downloads/gerrit-oauth-provider-master/gerrit/plugins/oauth/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/oauth/GitHubOAuthService.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
```

Since I've already compiled the plugins, this error shouldn't have been coming. I had also included the plugins as external jars (in eclipse) to see if these errors vanish, but to no avail. Can someone let me know the jar file that would contain the above classes?